Concatenating row, column indexes from a dataframe
I have one dataframe like this with the first column is the index (i.e., index = [1,2,3]):
    1      2      3
1   0      0.43   0.61
2   0.88   0      0.12
3   0.33   0.95   0

The new dataframe should look like the below:
Link      Value
1_1       0
1_2       0.43
1_3       0.61
2_1       0.88
2_2       0
2_3       0.12
3_1       0.33
3_2       0.95
3_3       0

Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you!

Simply do this
import pandas as pd

data = {
    1: [0, 0.43, 0.61],
    2: [0.88, 0, 0.12],
    3: [0.33, 0.95, 0]
}
index = [1, 2, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

df_melted = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index', var_name='Column', value_name='Value')
df_melted['Link'] = df_melted['index'].astype(str) + '_' + df_melted['Column'].astype(str)
df_result = df_melted[['Link', 'Value']]


df_result

which gives
 Link  Value
0  1_1   0.00
1  2_1   0.43
2  3_1   0.61
3  1_2   0.88
4  2_2   0.00
5  3_2   0.12
6  1_3   0.33
7  2_3   0.95
8  3_3   0.00


maybe because the answer could do with a bit more detail/explanation? but I'm not sure that's a heinous enough crime to warrant a downvote, a comment would've been more beneficial if that is the case than a downvote

I ask myself that too

You can use melt and post-process the columns (for example with assign and pop) to combine the index/column names:
out = (df.reset_index()
       .melt('index', var_name='Link', value_name='Value')
       .assign(Link=lambda x: x.pop('index').astype(str)+'_'+x['Link'].astype(str))
      )

Output:
  Link  Value
0  1_1   0.00
1  2_1   0.88
2  3_1   0.33
3  1_2   0.43
4  2_2   0.00
5  3_2   0.95
6  1_3   0.61
7  2_3   0.12
8  3_3   0.00

If the order of the rows matters, rather stack:
out = df.stack()
out.index = out.index.map(lambda x: '_'.join(map(str, x)))
out = out.rename_axis('Link').reset_index(name='Value')

Or use numpy:
out = pd.DataFrame({'Link': df.index.repeat(df.shape[1]).astype(str)
                            +'_'
                            +np.tile(df.columns, df.shape[0]).astype(str),
                    'Value': df.values.ravel()})

Output:
  Link  Value
0  1_1   0.00
1  1_2   0.43
2  1_3   0.61
3  2_1   0.88
4  2_2   0.00
5  2_3   0.12
6  3_1   0.33
7  3_2   0.95
8  3_3   0.00


to perform this transformation
import pandas as pd
data = {
    1: [0, 0.88, 0.33],
    2: [0.43, 0, 0.95],
    3: [0.61, 0.12, 0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[1, 2, 3])
df_reset = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Row'})
melted_df = df_reset.melt(id_vars=['Row'], var_name='Col', value_name='Value')
melted_df['Link'] = melted_df['Row'].astype(str) + '_' + melted_df['Col'].astype(str)
result_df = melted_df[['Link', 'Value']]
print(result_df)

the desired output format looks like :

